# Reactive redirection using go_router and flutter_bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

What would be the best way to somehow implement a reactive redirection using bloc states? Currently I'm doing redirection like this:

```
router.dart
final router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      name: OnBoardingPage.name,
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => OnBoardingPage(),
      redirect: (context, state) async {
        
        final homeLocation = '/login';
        if (isMobilePlatform) {
          final onBoardingCubit = context.read<OnBoardingCubit>();
          await onBoardingCubit.init();
          if (onBoardingCubit.state is DoNotShowOnBoarding) return homeLocation;

          return null;
        }

        return homeLocation;
      },
    ),
    GoRoute(
      name: 'login',
      path: '/login',
      builder: (context, state) => HomePage(),
    ),
  ],
);



onboardingpage.dart
class OnBoardingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static String name = 'oboarding';
  const OnBoardingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<OnBoardingCubit, OnBoardingState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is DoNotShowOnBoarding) {
          GoRouter.of(context).refresh();
        }
      },
      child: IntroductionScreen(
        rawPages: introductionPages(context),
        onDone: () => context.read<OnBoardingCubit>()..onBoardingIsCompleted(),
        next: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
        done: Text('done'.tr()),
        curve: Curves.easeInQuad,
        controlsMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        dotsDecorator: DotsDecorator(
          size: const Size.square(10.0),
          activeSize: const Size(20.0, 10.0),
          activeColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          spacing: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.0),
          activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However I do not like the fact hat I have to call GoRouter.of(context).refresh() in the bloc listener to trigger the redirection again. Is there a more professional way to work with flutter_bloc ?